# A boolean class member that compares the address of the class instance that is never used in code, but is public?

Tags: c++

This is a public function inside of a class which is meant to compare the addresses of instances of class RotaryEncoder.

I'm having trouble understanding what it does because it is never used in the code apart from declaration/definition.

```
bool RotaryEncoder::operator==(RotaryEncoder& b)
{
  return (this == &b);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thank you.

This is in C++.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your questions.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what it does. It compares the addresses. Without more information about where this class comes from and how it's expected to be used, I have no idea why someone would write its `operator==` to work this way.

Comment: *"it is never used"* -- Not knowing your background, I feel like this should be questioned. How did you determine it is not used? Searching for the text `operator==` is unlikely to succeed, as typical usage is of the form `a == b`, where `a` and `b` are `RotaryEncoder` objects. A more effective tactic would be to comment out the definition of this function (but leave the declaration) and see if the linker complains about the missing definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares *addresses* of the objects. That means an instance can only be "equal to" itself and no other instance. It's like replacing `a == b` with `&a == &b`. Note that this method most likely should be marked with `const noexcept` as well as `[[nodiscard]]`. And perhaps even `constexpr`, but that depends on the design. The argument should most likely be of type `const RotaryEncoder&` instead of `RotaryEncoder&`.